# How to send notifications according to time zone in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to send push notifications from my rails applications which are scheduled for every 7th day at 10am as cronjob using whenever gem.

Problem is that i have users from different time zones. from US,EU,AUS,IND etc. If I trigger from UTC time 10 am then users might get notifications at midnight, that's a very awful thing to do to disturb someone's sleep.

What can I do to schedule for every TimezoneUser to receive the notification at 10am of their timezone.

I am saving timezone for every user.

```
user_id time_zone
 153     +10:00
 155     +05:30
```

Answer (score 3):

I would schedule the job to run every hour the desired day of the week, check which users have the time 10am now and send to them. This way you run the job 24 times in one day of the week covering the whole world timezones.

```
every '0 * * * 1' do
  # Send notification to users that are at 10am now
end
```

In the above example, `0 * * * 1` is corresponding. `(at minute 0) (every hour) (every day) (every month) (first day of week -Monday-)`

If you want to send the notification on Sunday for example the number should be `7`, Tuesday is `2` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for answer @mohamed but its a hard coded scheduler. what should i do if the date is fetched from db. I am currently checking every 5 mins using a scheduler that if I should run a notification within 5 mins. 

that why i could not hard code in schedule.rb

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you may write a rake task, so you still have an access to Rails application writing Ruby and might run the task through cron job any time needed.

Your rake task at `lib/tasks/send_emails.rake` assuming your using PostgreSQL could be:

```
namespace :users do
  desc "use like rake users:send_emails"
    task send_emails: :environment do
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        users = User.where("current_timestamp::TIMESTAMPTZ AT TIME ZONE INTERVAL time_zone::INTERVAL > ?", Time.zone.parse("2016/07/06 00:00"))
        UsersMailer.send_newsletters(users).deliver_now
      end
    end
end
```

And then you set your cronjob to run a task rake like: 
     `0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd     /home/your_user_name/path_to_rails_application/current/ && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake users:send_emails RAILS_ENV=production --silent'`

Comment: hey @fercell could you elaborate more please it seems interesting but I don't have a clear idea.